# include in php doesnt work

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have two files(b.php and showimages.php)
b.php use this :

```
<?php include('showimages.php'); ?>
```

but it doesn't work but when I try to open showimages.php itself it shows the content.
whats the problem?

**b.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="product-row">
        <?php include('showimages.php'); ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**showimages.php:**

```
<?php
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'online_shopping');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM products "  ;   
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)  ;  
    header("Content-type: image/jpg"); 
    echo $row['pric1'];          
?>
```

Comment: You've given too little information, but the problem is probably that `header()` call in showimages.php

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the top of the script so you can get idea about the error. also create one config file and put your database configuration code in it

Comment: tell us; what do you see when you look at the HTML source? or have you left the question?

Comment: I love the "doesn't work". We see this day in and day out.

Answer (score 3):

Your HTML has already sent a header `Content-Type: text/html` so you can't send another one for an image. Instead of `include` you need to fetch the image via HTML:

```
<img src="showimages.php" alt="some image">
```

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner: Good catch, just used to closing tags.

Comment: wonder why your answer was downvoted; sure wasn't me but *au contraire* ;-)

Comment: May have had something inaccurate in there and kept rolling it back to the wrong revision, not sure.